# In cmake how do you use TARGET in file(GENERATE ... TARGET ...)

Tags: cmake

Docs imply that the TARGET option (new with 3.19) can be used for the generator expressions, however in the input how do you use the value input in the TARGET option?

```
$<TARGET_FILE:???>
```

tried a few things including `...`, `''` and just `$<TARGET_FILE>`. But always get `Error evaluating generator expression:`

```
--Docs
TARGET <target>
New in version 3.19.

Specify which target to use when evaluating generator expressions that require a target for evaluation (e.g. $<COMPILE_FEATURES:...>, $<TARGET_PROPERTY:prop>).

--Release notes
The file(GENERATE) command gained a new TARGET keyword to support resolving target-dependent generator expressions.
```

Comment: After reading the docs again and looking up the example generator expressions I get the feeling it only works with expressions that don't require a target in the call, seems pretty limiting feature to include. Anyone know for sure?

Comment: Try out simply specifying the target name as you would in other generator expressions and don't worry about the `TARGET` option. to me this reads like specifying the `TARGET` option just is relevant for generator expressions referring to the current target, such as `$<TARGET_PROPERTY:prop>`